# Bind command to Loaded event of view

Tags: wpf, xaml, commandbinding

I am trying to get a method to run when a view has finished loading. I have tried to bind a command to the `Loaded` event in the view but it fails to run. The inner exception that is thrown is

> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.' 
>   Line number '14' and line position '14'

```
<UserControl x:Class="Components.Map.MapView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Components.Map"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.Controls;assembly=Windows.Controls"
             xmlns:ValidationRules="clr-namespace:Windows.Controls.ValidationRules;assembly=Windows.Controls"
             xmlns:directGraphicsControl="clr-namespace:Windows.DirectGraphicsControl;assembly=Windows.DirectGraphicsControl"
             xmlns:colorBar="clr-namespace:Components.Common.ColorBar;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:RefinedRibbonControls="clr-namespace:Components.Common.Controls.RefinedRibbonControls;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:Components.Common.UserControls;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:map1="clr-namespace:Models.Map;assembly=Models.Map"
             xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:Windows.Utilities;assembly=Windows.Utilities"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Loaded="{Binding Path=MapControlViewModel.MapLoadedCommand}">
```

How am I able to bind to a view’s `Loaded` event so I can run something after the view has finished loading?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to bind command to the `Loaded` event, you should use the "System.Windows.Interactivity" assembly.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Components.Map.MapView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Components.Map"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.Controls;assembly=Windows.Controls"
             xmlns:ValidationRules="clr-namespace:Windows.Controls.ValidationRules;assembly=Windows.Controls"
             xmlns:directGraphicsControl="clr-namespace:Windows.DirectGraphicsControl;assembly=Windows.DirectGraphicsControl"
             xmlns:colorBar="clr-namespace:Components.Common.ColorBar;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:RefinedRibbonControls="clr-namespace:Components.Common.Controls.RefinedRibbonControls;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:Components.Common.UserControls;assembly=Components.Common"
             xmlns:map1="clr-namespace:Models.Map;assembly=Models.Map"
             xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:Windows.Utilities;assembly=Windows.Utilities"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">

             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</UserControl>
```

System.Windows.Interactivity.dll is in Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) ([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)) and also available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/).

Comment: +1 Beat me by seconds, though I was going to go the `CallMethodAction` action route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, there is no need to download the .dll because it is already located in .NET framework assemblies (`...\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`)

Comment: Looks like "System.Windows.Interactivity" has been open sourced. Checkout https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf .

Comment: This  Nuget package has been deprecated as it is legacy and no longer maintained. The download link is also broken.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install nuget package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf
   (System.Windows.Interactivity is deprecated)
2. Add xmlns to window/user control.
   `xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`
3. Add Trigger to main window

```
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Command="{Binding MyLoadedCommand}"/>
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
```