# How to Bind command to Loaded event of form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to run some code when the main form is loaded. I used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933102/bind-command-to-loaded-event-of-view). I am using wpf with .NET core 3.1 using the MVVM pattern. When I try to add the nuget package `System.Windows.Interactivity` I get an error `This package may not be fully compatible with your project`. I am assuming the issue is the version of .NET I am using. Is there a way to make this work for .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf

Comment: @Andy do I use this like I would with `System.Windows.Interactivity`

Comment: Yes and no. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

Answer (score 3):

System.Windows.Interactivity has been replaced by a nuget package.

Instead of referencing that you add the package:

Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf

You will then need an xmlns.

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/
( see for more info ).

Steps to migrate are:

Remove reference to “Microsoft.Expression.Interactions” and “System.Windows.Interactivity”
Install the “Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf” NuGet package.
XAML files – replace the xmlns namespaces “http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity” and “http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions“with “http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors“
C# files – replace the usings in c# files “Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity” and “Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions” with “Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors”

This is net core friendly.

It is not exactly like for like and I found one piece of my code incompatible. For most people this is likely a non-issue though.